# Parse date with 2-digit year

Tags: php, php-carbon

I want to parse a string of the form `02.01.19 13:49`  with [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Now `\Carbon\Carbon::parse('02.01.19 13:49');` fails with

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (20.01.19 13:49)
>   at position 9 (1): Double time specification

Is there any way to tell Carbon that the `19` represents 2019?

This is how I managed to do it, buts its a bit ugly:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse(
    preg_replace('/(\d\d\.\d\d\.)(\d\d) /','${1}20$2 ', '02.01.19 13:49')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `Carbon::createFromFormat()` to create a carbon instance from a custom date format string.

```
Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m.d.y H:i', '02.01.19 13:49');
```

You can reference the PHP date format string from http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

```
Carbon::createFromFormat("d.m.y H:i", "02.01.19 13:49");
```

This could solve the issue if the input format is fixed.

Comment: Damn, too late:)